# specfic npm package not working in node.js? issue: perl rules/compile-rules.pl 'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, perl, npm, package, npm-install

this is the package
i have installed the package using the npm install command and then made sure my package.json has type: module for the import to work,in my code I have included

on their website it says they have a runtime compilation rule but I am not sure what they mean by that or what I have to do to get this package working on visual studio code ide with node.js

in my code I have included :

```js
// hithere.js
import { scin, snSave } from "scen";
console.log("hi")
```

however I get this error after running node hithere.js in my terminal

```
rojects\\node_modules\\scigen\\lib\\index.js'←[39m
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using windows OS?

Comment: yes i am using windows os

Answer (score 2):

You need to install [perl](https://strawberryperl.com/) in your system and then add it to your config path.

Comment: You are providing a link to padre with a perl5.12 bundled. This is outdated. Recent perl versions can be found at https://strawberryperl.com/

Comment: I've fixed the "install Perl" link, but I'll also update the learn.perl.org page so that it doesn't promote obsolete projects.